# Are there any fields in EE that overlap with Quantum informatics/computing nowadays?

Tags: computer-architecture, analog-computer, research, information

As I understand it, research in quantum information and computing has traditionally been confined to physics and applied physics/math departments.  It seems to me that many of the practical challenges associated with physically implementing quantum computers (or extending the capabilities of existing systems, e.g. D-wave and whatever Microsoft's Station Q is up to) would be of interest to electrical engineers, and university faculty in particular.

This question may come across as a bit naïve, but is this in fact the case? What areas of EE overlap with quantum computing? Are there EE professors and/or researchers who are branching out into quantum computing and quantum information or related topics?

Comment: Perhaps that may be affected by which Universities are under consideration.

Comment: I disagree with this question being closed. It can be better worded, sure, but the gist is asking about what areas of EE might overlap with Quantum computing. I don't see how answering to that will be opinion based, the research in EE that helps QC exists, is useful, and should be talked about. I don't see how opinion fits into a potential answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While making a quantum processor falls out of the electrical engineering field, currently there's a lot of research going on on making integrated electronics to read out qubits that, obviously, falls into our lap.

The challenge is that they have to work at 4 kelvin, which is not that far from the few mK that the quantum processor works at. They want to do this as a step forward to place the readout electronics closer to the quantum processor (rather than having them both in separate rooms and electronics being at ambient temperature with lots of cables pulled between rooms).

At my former uni, TU Delft, there's a research theme called Cryo-CMOS that focuses on making CMOS transceivers for qubit readout that work at such low temperature. I work on CMOS circuits, too, but I mostly make sure my designs are fully functional down to -40°C, while they have to make it work down to -269°C. Typical foundry models used in the industry do not go down to those temperatures.

I know of, at least, 3 professors who used to focus on diverse topics such as digital design, electronic instrumentation and RF who are now working on this cryoCMOS stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Review the [7 big challenges](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DiVincenzo%27s_criteria) of practical quantum computers and ask yourself which of those fall into the domain of EE. Hint: none. I guess there will be a subfield of QEE, once quantum computers have become practical and somewhat standardized.

And it is not surprising: While electronic computers (both analog and digital) are one type of computer, quantum computers can well be considered to be *another*, i e. in general *non-electronic* computer, because in general it doesn't use *charge* as information carriers. So by design, quantum computers are not electronic engineering.

Still, at some level, all quantum computers require an electronic interface to classical computers, which is EE. So as with most technology, EE have their place in the value chain of quantum computing, but are not directly concerned with the core functionalities.